# Firefox Add-on SDK and js-ctypes

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm trying to use Firefox Add-on SDK with js-ctypes to access the methods of a local DLL, but it isn't working.

The main.js code:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "mysite.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("myjs.js")
});
```

The myjs.js code is just:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
alert("hello world");
```

On Firefox's console I got those messages:

```
The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
TypeError: Components.utils is undefined
```

No "hello world" alert is fired.

What's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use js-ctypes from a content script - content scripts have no privileges. You have to do that in the extension itself, via [chrome authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority):

```js
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", null);
var lib = ctypes.open(...);
```

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. I can't "require" inside a Content Script also. I have to use ctypes inside main.js and make the scripts communicate. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a ctypes issue.

You can't alert from that context. alert is a method on window. So you can do one of two things:

1. Get the most recent window and run alert there.

   ```
   Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
   Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).alert('hello world');
   ```
2. Use prompts service: [example at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIPromptService#alert_example)

   ```
   Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
   Services.prompts.alert(null, 'Hello World TITLE', 'hello world message');
   ```

Also if you are using addon sdk you dont have access to `Components` so you can't do `Components.utils.import` you will have to put at top of your main.js this `const {Cu} = require('chrome');` then you can do `Cu.import('blah')`

Comment: A content script can very well use `alert()`, it runs in the context of a window - that's not the issue here.